# How can I get percentile of column in dataframe considering only previous values? (Python)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, percentile

I have a dataframe with a numeric column and I would link to calculate the percentile of the values in each row for that column considering only previous rows of the column. Here is an example:

```
+-------+
| col_1 |
+-------+
|  5    |
+-------+
|  4    |
+-------+
|  10   |
+-------+
|  1    |
+-------+
|  7    |
+-------+
```

I would like to obtain a dataframe like this:

```
+-------+------------+
| col_1 | percentile |
+-------+------------+
|  5    |     100    |
+-------+------------+
|  4    |     50     |
+-------+------------+
|  10   |     100    |
+-------+------------+
|  1    |     25     |
+-------+------------+
|  7    |     80     |
+-------+------------+
```

How can I calculate it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try as follows.

- Use [`df.expanding`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.expanding.html) with `min_periods=1` to allow expanding window calculations.
- For each window, we apply [`Expanding.rank`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.core.window.expanding.Expanding.rank.html) with `pct=True` (and we multiply by `100`).

We can assign the result directly to the new column `percentile`:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'col_1':[5,4,10,1,7]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['percentile'] = df['col_1'].expanding(min_periods=1).rank(pct=True).mul(100)

print(df)

   col_1  percentile
0      5       100.0
1      4        50.0
2     10       100.0
3      1        25.0
4      7        80.0
```

**Update**: `Expanding.rank` was added to `pandas` in version `1.4.0`. For earlier versions, you could for instance try:

```
temp = df['col_1'].expanding(min_periods=1).agg(['rank','count'])
df['percentile'] = (temp['rank']/temp['count']).mul(100)

print(df)

   col_1  percentile
0      5       100.0
1      4        50.0
2     10       100.0
3      1        25.0
4      7        80.0
```

Or, as a one-liner:

```
df['percentile'] = df['col_1'].expanding(min_periods=1)\
    .apply(lambda x: (x.rank()/x.count()).to_numpy()[-1]*100)
```

Comment: Thanks for the wuick response, but I got the error: "AttributeError: 'Expanding' object has no attribute 'rank'"...

Comment: What is your version of `pandas`? You can check with `print(pd.__version__)`. The `rank` feature for expanding was added in version `1.4.0`.

Comment: My version is 1.1.3, and I can't update it because it would change other compatibility issues...

Comment: Updated the answer, let me know if the second option works for your version.

Comment: it works! Thanks! I was looking for something faster than using .apply and lambda functions but it works :) Anyway, is there any way of doing it faster?